# Why doesn't this custom sourcing function make my declared variable globally available?

Tags: bash, scope, global-variables

I'm facing a very weird issue. I know I'm missing something basic but for the life of me I can't quite figure out what.

Consider these declarations in a file `tmp.sh`:

```
declare -A aa
aa[1]=hello
aa[2]=world

myfunc() {
    echo exists
}

myvar=exists
```

I source the script as `source tmp.sh` and run:

```
myfunc
echo $myvar
echo ${aa[@]}
```

The output is:

```
exists
exists
hello world
```

Now I do the same thing but put the source statement in a function:

```
mysource() {
    filename="$1"
    source "$filename" 
}
```

This time the output is:

```
exists
exists
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Any reason your using ass array when your are using numbers as keys?

Comment: The associative array isn't really relevant; *any* variable created by `declare` will exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-g` option to `declare`. <sup>[1]</sup>

From the manual

> -g create global variables when used in a shell function; otherwise ignored (by default, declare declares local scope variables when used in shell functions)

Also useful to mention from chepner's comment below

> source works by executing the contents of the file exactly as if you replaced the source command with contents of the file. Even though the declare statements are not in a function in your file, they are part of the function that calls source.

---

<sup>[1] The `-g` option requires [Bash 4.2 or above](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS).</sup>

Comment: Thanks. But how does myvar get into global scope then?

Comment: `source` works by executing the contents of the file *exactly* as if you replaced the source command with contents of the file. Even though the `declare` statements are not in a  function in your file, they *are* part of the function that calls `source`.

Comment: @KshitizSharma What do you mean? It doesn't... Your output shows myvar is still set globally.

Comment: I meant global scope. How am I able to print value for myvar? Secondly, `-g` gives this: `-bash: source: -g: invalid option`

Comment: @KshitizSharma The g flag is for declare, apologies for not making that clear.

Comment: @chepner Wasn't `-A` as well?

Comment: I deleted the comment because while `-A` was introduced in 4.0, it's not common to be stuck with 4.0 or 4.1. (That is, if your distribution has 4.0 available, it *probably* is pretty good about making newer 4.x versions available as they are released, so limiting support to 4.0 or 4.1 seems rare these days.)

Comment: (Granted, I'm using an OS at work that is pinned at 4.1, but in general people asking `bash` questions on SO seem to be using at least 4.2, unless they are on macOS and using the system `bash`.)

Comment: @123 I think you should add chepner's comment to your answer to make it more complete. source behaves as if the code was copy pasted at that location, so it becomes local to the `mysource` function. Adding an echo inside `mysource` works.

Comment: 123, @chepner: I took the liberty of adding the 4.2+ requirement to the answer after all. Since the question is ultimately not specific to `-A` declarations (I've also generalized the title), this information may be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

To complement [123's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40550107/45375):

- By default, `declare` creates a *local* variable when used in a *function* (to put it differently: inside a function, `declare` by default behaves the same as `local`).
- To create a *global* variable from inside a function:

  - Bash `4.2+`:

    - use `declare -g` (e.g., `declare -g foo='bar'`)
  - Older Bash versions, including `3.x`:

    - simply *assign a value* to the variable (e.g., `foo='bar'`), do not use `declare`.

---

As an aside:

Your sample code uses `declare -A` to declare an associative array, which requires Bash `4.0`.

Associative arrays are the only types of (non-environment) variables that strictly *need* a `declare` statement for their creation - you cannot create an associative array without `declare -A`, whereas you can create (non-integer-typed) scalars and arrays implicitly by simple assignment.

Thus, given that `declare -g` requires Bash `4.2`, there is no solution to your problem if you happen to be stuck on `4.0` or `4.1`.

`3.x` versions of Bash don't face this problem, because they don't support `declare -A` altogether.